# BlackBerry non-UI click event listener

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am running the following code in my application. When this code is executed, it displays a global screen alert (OK, Cancel).

```
final Dialog _dialog = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, "Message", Dialog.OK, Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION), Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
Application.getApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ui.pushGlobalScreen(_dialog, 0, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
    }
});
```

If the user clicks 'OK', then I want to go some other class. Else nothing. How is this done?. How can I find out which button was clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement DialogClosedListener interface and override the dialogClosed() method.

this code example will help you.

after your _dialog.show(0); set the listener for dialog close.

```
_dialog.setDialogClosedListener(new MyDialogClosedListener());
```

now make inner class as follows:-

```
 public class MyDialogClosedListener implements DialogClosedListener
    {

    public void dialogClosed(Dialog dialog, int choice) 
    {
        if(dialog.equals(_dialog))
        {
            if(choice == -1)
            {

            }
            if(choice == 1)
            {
                your code to implement
            }
            else if(choice == 2)
            {

                your code to implement  
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: the dialog is displayed in global screen. so how i get the value of click event ?

Comment: It also listens the global event.

Comment: I given you that code. Implement dialogClosedListener in your class and do the things which are shown in above code.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking for is this:

```
string confirmationDialogMessage = "Are you sure you want to do this?";
if (Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, confirmationDialogMessage) == Dialog.OK) {
  //do something
}
else {
  //do nothing
}
```

You **don't** need to create a new instance of `Dialog` or implement the `DialogClosedListener` Interface.

(see http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Dialog.html for additional information).

Comment: how to display this in global screen ?. how to create new instance of dialog ?

Comment: .ask() is a static method on the Dialog class, so you can call it without creating an instance of Dialog. This method call displays the dialog as you would expect, unless I'm misinterpreting what you mean by 'global screen'? It's a modal dialog, so you can't interact with anything else on the screen until you click on OK or Cancel.

Comment: Dialog.ask will display in foreground, when my app running in background ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what will happen.

Comment: You don't need to call this code using the pushGlobalScreen method, because you don't need to USE the pushGloablScreen method. You can replace ALL of the code in your question with my code snippet above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4681/discussion-between-rez-john-and-ryan-shripat)